# Is it possible to provision leaf device through iot edge device?

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, provisioning, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have implemented Azure IoT edge transparent gateway use case and was able to register/provision my leaf device through DPS(x509).

But I want to register my leaf device on IoT Hub through IoT edge as my leaf devices doesn't have any Internet connection thus they can't access IoT Hub interface.

Or I'm open for other solutions too for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Right now IoT Edge does not support proxying DPS requests. you would need to provision your device "manually"

Comment: since you cannot reach DPS from your device you will probably end up registering this device directly in IoT Hub (and assign it as child device to your edge device) and will need to bring creds onto the device somehow. it depends on your attestation mechanism. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities

Comment: alternatively you can go through DPS from an application but it will need to have device's creds to do attestation